# Difference between adjacent rows of a column in IPython notebook

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a query in IPython where I have grouped the dataframe based on MachineName, LocalIPAddress, SourceAddress and DateTime and I get the output as below.

### MachineName LocalIPAddress SourceAddress DateTime

BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186    " "           2016-04-13 03:42:29.865

BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186    " "           2016-04-13 08:48:33.005

BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186    " "           2016-04-13 10:16:28.612

BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186    " "           2016-04-13 10:31:33.343

BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186    " "           2016-04-13 13:43:00.173

BMTSAFT04   10.3.0.186    " "           2016-04-13 20:02:11.610

---

BMTSYSP05   10.1.9.25   10.3.4.81        2016-04-13 06:08:53.584

BMTSYSP05   10.1.9.25   10.3.4.81        2016-04-13 12:01:57.563

---

Now for each group I have to find the difference between the datetime of corresponding rows in the group.

For example, in first group, I have to display difference between "2016-04-13 03:42:29.865" and "2016-04-13 08:48:33.005", difference between "2016-04-13 08:48:33.005" and "2016-04-13 10:16:28.612","2016-04-13 10:16:28.612" and "2016-04-13 10:31:33.343" and so on. This has to be done for all the groups in the table.

I am new to python and I am figuring out on how this can be achieved.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  4  5  6  7
2  2  4  6  8
3  3  2  1  4
4  0  1  2  4

In [6]: df['diff'] = df['d'] - df['d'].shift(-1)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   a  b  c  d  diff
0  1  2  3  4    -3
1  4  5  6  7    -1
2  2  4  6  8     4
3  3  2  1  4     0
4  0  1  2  4   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately this does not work with DateTime objects.

I have a series of DateTime objects in my DataFrame:

[2016-04-13 03:42:29.865,

2016-04-13 08:48:33.005,

2016-04-13 10:16:28.612,

2016-04-13 10:31:33.343,

2016-04-13 13:43:00.173,

2016-04-13 20:02:11.610]

I need to find the difference between the hours and  minutes of consecutive DateTime objects. For example, difference between 
2016-04-13 08:48:33.005 and 2016-04-13 03:42:29.865 is 5 hrs and 6 minutes. Similarly, I have to find the difference between third and second DateTime objects.

Comment: Can you try, df['diff'] = (df['DateTime'] - df['DateTime'].shift(-1)).astype('timedelta64[h]')

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but still no results, i.e. grouping the df dataframe based om 'MachineName','LocalIPAddress','SourceAddress' and 'DateTime' and then subtracting the dates from each other. 


df2 = df.groupby(['MachineName','LocalIPAddress','SourceAddress','DateTime'])[(df['DateTime'] - df['DateTime'].shift(-1)).astype('timedelta64[h]']

Comment: I am not sure if you need groupby here.